# Can't tell whats causing the white space between divs using Firebug

Tags: html, css, layout, firebug

I have some broken HTML on this page: http://www.problemio.com/category.php?category_id=1

Specifically, I can not tell why there is white space between `<div class="nav_bar">` and `<div class="banner">`

Would anyone be able to help me understand why this is happening? I am looking in Firebug and it says nothing about that white space there. Ideally, I'd get rid of the white space.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you inspect with Firebug or Dev tools you'll see that you have an inline css style. Get rid of that margin and problem solved.

`<div id="search" style="margin-top: 7px;">`

Comment: ah good call. But then that leads me to the next point of confusion - why doesn't the search and the categories dropdown don't sit on the same horizontal height like they sit on problemio.com home page ? Any idea?

Comment: Well in your home page the div with class `nav` takes the values from `main_index.css` but in the other page it's taking values from `main.css`. Some rules are different that's why is not consistent. I suggest you learn how to use firebug or devtools to solve these kind of problems.